# override css for html5 form validation/required popup

Tags: css, html, popup, validation

How can I override the default popup for a required field on a HTML5 form?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uKZGp/ (make sure you click the submit button to see the popup)

The HTML

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*" required="required" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

NOTE: You must view this with a HTML5 browser like Google Chrome or FireFox.

This link doesn't solve my question but it might make someone think outside of the box:

- http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/
- http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2011/03/styling-with-html5-form-validation.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you style the HTML5 form validation messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713405/how-do-you-style-the-html5-form-validation-messages)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's impossible to change the validation style with only HTML/CSS.

It's part of the browser. The only attribute I figured out to change is the error message by using this example:

```
 document.getElementById("name").setCustomValidity("Lorum Ipsum");
```

But, as shown in this example : http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/qTV3g/, you can override the panel style by using jQuery. This is not a plugin, it's a core functionality, uses a DOM lib called [Webshims](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/) and, of course, some CSS to style the popups.

I found that very useful example in this [bug post](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602500) titled `Improve form validation error panel UI`.

I think this is the best solution you can find and only way to override the basic (ugly) error panel.

Comment: I did add another link to my question, might help (or not). Good suggestion though, thanks.

Answer (score 24):

I'm not sure why, but `::-webkit-validation-bubble-message { display: none; }` wouldn't work for me.
I was able to get the desired result (tested in FF 19, Chrome Version 29.0.1547.76 m) by preventing the default behavior of the invalid event, which does not bubble.

```js
document.addEventListener(
  "invalid",
  (event) => {
    // Prevent the browser from showing the default error bubble/hint.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Optionally fire off some custom validation handler.
    myValidationFunction(event);
  },
  { capture: true },
);
```

Comment: Upvoted this because for anyone looking for a solution to this answer circa 2014 this is the only one I have found to have worked. +additional props for the creative use of the invalid event listener. Thanks very much for taking the time to post your solution man it's helped me a lot!

Comment: You can remove the uneeded IIFE here :)

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome, Chromium, and other Blink-based browsers because Google removed `::-webkit-validation-bubble` in [Chrome 28 in July 2013](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050) and the functionality since has not been restored. As of early 2020, WebKit and Apple Safari  still support it though.

Comment: Great solution! Most forms have its own validation styling. This really helped. It even allows the event to propagate, which I viscerally thought it wouldn't

Answer (score 13):

For webkit, you can use `::-webkit-validation-bubble-message`. For example to hide it:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message { display: none; }
```

There are also:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-outer-arrow{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-inner-arrow{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message{}
```

**Update:** Chrome does not allow styling form validation bubbles anymore: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050

For firefox you can experiment with `:-moz-placeholder {}`.

Answer (score 4):

The current default email validation is currently one of the ugliest things I have ever seen Google design!

[image: Chrome HTML5 email type form validation]

However it seems to be contained in a standard `div` so you can make some changes to it, if you remember to then reset these values.

I've found you can alter the background, font size and colour, border and shadow, like so

```
div {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #333;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

If you then overwrite these for divs inside the html tag, then only the validation is ultimately affected.

```
html div {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Unfortunately some of the key attributes that you'd want to change, such as `margin` and `font-weight`, cannot be altered.

NB. This technique currently only works for Chrome (12), i.e. not work for Firefox 4, Opera 11 or Safari (Win 7).

Answer (score 3):

Appended a class to the input type. and displayed message there .Hope that helps after little customization. working codepen:

```js
document.querySelector('#frm').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('submitted');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ffa500;
}
form > div {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.theTooltip {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  will-change: opacity, visibility;
  max-width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(15%, -50%);
          transform: translate(15%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 100;
}
.theTooltip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}
input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: text;
  padding: 7px;
}
input:focus,
input:active {
  outline: none;
}
.submitted input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.submitted input:invalid ~ .theTooltip {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.submitted input:valid ~ .theTooltip {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm" action="action">
  <div>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" required="required"/><span class="theTooltip">Invalid email</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button formnovalidate="formnovalidate">OK</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is a rather old question but I have found this library that I think this may be beneficial to other that find this.

http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html