# Styling for <input required ...> in WebKit

Tags: css, forms, html, webkit, required

Please take a look at this example in Chrome browser: http://jsfiddle.net/ymzTB/

```
<form>
    <input required type = "text" >
    <input type = "submit" >
</form>
```

When you leave the input empty and just click enter, you'll receive a message like this: `Please fill out this field.` which looks nice.

How can I style this message in WebKit and other browsers, say, replace the background color with red, or set the font color or size to something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [override css for html5 form validation/required popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use following [pseudo classes](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls):

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-outer-arrow{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-inner-arrow{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message{}
```