# how can i show customised form validation error message in symfony2

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

[This is the link to my form window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChYB2.png)

Can anybody suggest how to customize the error messages in my form window like - 'This value is not valid', 'Passwords do not match' to appear like a pop up error message for empty field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean form theme customization, you can check out the official doc:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 5):

Validation error messages can be customized at your bundles `validation.yml` file. I have added an example.

```
# src/Vendor/YourBundleName/Resources/config/validation.yml
Vendor\YourBundleName\Entity\YourModel:
    properties:
        email:
            - Email:
                message: The email you entered is not a valid email.
            - NotBlank
                message: Please enter email.
```

Please read [validation doc section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) and [validation constraint reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html) carefully.

Comment: What if I have a form which does not consist of ant entity?

Comment: If you are familiarized with the form window image then you would have guessed that the form is a registration form bound to User entity. That's why my answer was related to entity. For forms not bound to entity refer to documentation or search around Google or post a question in SO if you don't find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: I have searched but could not find any satisfactory answer :(

Thanks any wyz

Comment: Here is a hint, search for "callback validator"

Comment: @m2mdas , as I can add those messages to the form type validation with html5 validation

Comment: @webyseo, to mimic client side validation with Symfony2 server side validation checkout [jsFormValidatorBundle](https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle). Although it does not touch html5 validation message, adding this feature should not be hard as the bundle is customizable.

Answer (score 3):

It's not symfony but the browser's implementation of the "required" attribute which display these ugly alert messages. Looks like we can't customize this attribute with html/css only but you can try to play around with jquery to customize the error messages before htm5 catch the user input.

Someone asked something similar, hope it can help you:  [override css for html5 form validation/required popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup)

Comment: in symfony2 form validation error how can i show like html5 form validation error. IS there any way in symfony2 so i can show form validation error like empty field error message show when form is submit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you search for invalid_message.
you can customize your message just like following code block:

```
$inputsForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add("networkAddress", TextType::class,[
            'required'=>true
            ])
        ->add("hostsCount",NumberType::class, [
            'required'=>true,
            'invalid_message'=>'my error message!'
        ])
        ->add('calc',SubmitType::class,['label'=>'Berechnen'])
        ->getForm();
```