# How to change input pattern language from the html5 codes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use input pattern html5 validation. My computer default language is Turkish, so I get the warning message in Turkish. Is there any way to change the warning message language from the codes so every visitor gets the message in language I select?

**http://jsfiddle.net/xhqsB/104/**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern=".{5,10}">
      <input type="submit" value="Check"></input>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Is appearing in Turkish because it is the language of your browser. Try changing the language of the browser and check if the message appears in English, for example.

Comment: Pilha, please read the question again. I don't want to change any setting. I want to change it from the codes, so every visitor sees the same message.

Comment: In that case you can set `setCustomValidity` per javascript for the field fixed to the message you want and in whatever language you want.

Comment: Right, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Comment: Pilha, they are not input type. I search an answer for input pattern.

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu The way you want to have it is not existing. There is no input pattern to change the language of an input. The only way to force the standard behavior of using the system language is by overwriting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you want to have it is not existing. There is no input pattern to change the language of an input. The only way to force a change of the standard behavior of using the system language is by overwriting it.

By following the links in the comments above, you will see an example how to overwrite it.

Comment: To be exact, the language of the `input` element can be set (using the `lang` attribute), but this has no effect on browsers’s error messages. The problem is that the the HTML5 features like `pattern` were not designed with localization in mind. Or, rather, they imply the idea that the interface is localized by the browser according to the *browser* locale, not the page locale.

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite the validation message as explained in this article:
[HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)