# Override default css stylings for validation in IE9 +

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9

http://jsfiddle.net/4LXkE/

The code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*" required="required" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In the above fiddle, you can see that in IE9+ (that's what my target browser is) the input box is surrounded by an ugly red highlight and a popup message to show it is a required field. 
I found the following question which is close, but doesn't give a full answer to my specific question:

[override css for html5 form validation/required popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup)

In my application I have my own stylings (twitter bootstrap defaults) but they are hidden behind these styles which show up.

While I tried to debug the app in Developer tools, i couldn't find what CSS classes were being added or how.

Any help turning these off would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Wish I had a cryptic browser to reproduce the issue and help more :-P

Comment: @NicholasHazel, we seem to keep looking at the same questions!

Comment: I bounce all over the place for `html`, `css`, `javascript`, and `jquery` issues. Glad to see fellow coders helping as well, as that is my only purpose on this site (unless I get a real tricky problem :-P )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IE9 does not support the "required" attribute natively, and it is not part of the UA stylesheet.**

Are you using Modernizr or something similar along with Bootstrap? In IE9, the "required" attribute is useless without a polyfill. (see caniuse or [this article](http://people.mozilla.org/~prouget/ie9/) for more information) Please [look at Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#web-forms) for a solution to this problem. If you're using a polyfill already, you should be able to style the shim element to get the appearance you want.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. I have modernizr in my application where this caused issues. The jsfiddle I tested in IE10 and that's why it showed the error. I will look into modernizr :)