# AngularJS field validation->styling "popup"

Tags: css, angularjs

Is there a way to style the "popup" when a field is invalid in AngularJS?

[image]

I have no idea WHERE this thing is styled? We also have Bootstrap loaded, not sure if it's there. Can't right-click to "find element" either.

Comment: You might want to give a look a this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the browser validation kicking in. Disable it as follows:

```
<form novalidate></form>
```

**Edit**: Example of a form using novalidate with AngularJS's validation:

```
 <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
Name:
     <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="uName" required /><br />
E-mail:
     <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required/><br />
     <div ng-show="form.uEmail.$dirty && form.uEmail.$invalid">Invalid:
         <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
         <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
     </div>
</form>
```

I believe it is no longer possible to style these popups:

[Link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050)

Comment: Can I use a jQuery validation plugin along with AngularJS?

Comment: Also, would that attribute prohibit ng-validate working?

Comment: MB34 yes and it's quite easy to use but too much hicky :)

Comment: ng-validate will continue to work as normal. Using jQuery validation alongside Angular's is not advisable.