# Styling default validation tooltip

Tags: html, css, validation, tooltip

Is it possible to style the default tooltip? Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yccgyq3y/)  demonstrating the default tooltip.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Submit without entering value" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Tool tip for required ? Or you need style in placeholder ?

Comment: The tooltip that displays when a required field is not filled out.

Comment: Please check this : https://jsfiddle.net/greypants/zgCb7/

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for. I want to know if the default tooltip can be styled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not change "default tooltip" (HTML5 validation bubble) - it is determinated by browser vendor and several other params like browser language.

You can, however, **prevent validation bubble** - by doing something like

```
<input placeholder="Lorem ipsum..." required oninvalid="myCustomFunction()" />
```

From now on, with `myCustomFunction` you can develop your own bubble.

[Reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css to style placeholder text

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome */
  color: red;
}
```