# Issue with the html 5 validation message position

Tags: html, google-chrome, validation

I am working on an application which uses the html 5 validations. When user fill any invalid value in the form and tries to submit the form, then the error message pops up. This works fine in IE and Firefox, however, in google chrome the position of the pop up message messed up.How to fix the position of the error popup in the chrome.
Below are the screen shot.

**Firefox**
[image]

**Chrome**
[image]

Comment: You can refer to this for positioning the error popup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup